# Start new K8s Pod within K8s Pod without "Privileges"

Tags: docker, authentication, kubernetes

Good day,

I have quite a problem.

In our K8s Cluster should be a Simulations Starter Service (= "Master Pod") that can create Pods (= "Child Pods"). For each new request (in this case something like "start simulation") the Service starts a new simulation pod.

Also, I don't have extra privileges like "Privileged" ([Pod Security Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/)). We know we could connect to the same cluster by setting the kubernetes context and use kubectl in the Master Pod. But this is quite hacky and ugly since the Master Pod now would have a hell lot of power over the cluster (and so himself). Power he wouldn't really need and this can't be best practice.

I am new to kubernetes and docker (started to discover them a week ago) and its a pretty tough task for me I may say.

Any ideas appreciated!

Edit:
I checked Google and StackOverflow search and didn't really find anything.

Comment: Could you explain it further? As I understand, you want to spawn a pod once a request comes. How will you be fetching the request? What kind of simulation will it start?

Comment: The plan is that the Starter Service (Master Pod) has a REST API. If a new POST/PUT (not clear yet)  comes in with certain data to a certain ressource, the simulation will be started.

The Simulations it self is a Multi Agent Simulation with potential just a few Agents up to a million or more. The have a number of "Ticks", which are simulation steps. It depends on the simulation how long it takes in total. In some cases it takes days / weeks to compute all Ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my colleague found something. 
Job Queueing.
I think thats exactly what we wanted and actually it just kinda needs rights (depends on your specific deployment) to deploy but after that works just fine.

I was to focused on pods, so I completely missed the existence of Jobs.

If someone comes along here, try out their job queueing tutorial with Rabbitmq in their [Github Repository](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.3/examples/celery-rabbitmq).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/).

There are many **Officially-supported Kubernetes client libraries**:

> Go - [github.com/kubernetes/client-go/](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/)
>
> Python - [github.com/kubernetes-client/python/](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/)
>
> Java - [github.com/kubernetes-client/java](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/)
>
> dotnet - [github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp)
>
> JavaScript - [github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript)

There are also many **community supported** ones which are listed [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries#community-maintained-client-libraries).

As an example, we can use [official python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/) client library.

Installation:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python.git
cd python
python setup.py install
```

From  [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kubernetes/)  directly:

```
pip install kubernetes
```

And use this [example deployment script](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/deployment_examples.py).

Detailed installation, requirements and usage is available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md).

Comment: I am afraid that will not work, since this is our current way. And in our current way the starter Service / Pod is privileged so he can start other pods. Without these privileged I am afraid it will not work. Thats why we are looking for a new way in the first place.